# C++ 11 code compiles with `clang++`, but not with `clang -x c++`

Tags: clang, sublimetext2, clang++

### Basic Problem

I have the following code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdint>
using namespace std;
int main ()
{
  int32_t spam;
  spam=5;
  cout << "Hello World! We like " << spam << endl;
  return 0;
}
```

This compiles nicely when I do `clang++ -stdlib=libc++ cpptest.cpp`. However, the otherwise excellent SublimeClang parser for Sublime Text 2 doesn't seem to understand it. I figured that might be because it uses `clang -x c++` instead of `clang++`, and tried to compile my snippet above using `clang -x c++ -std=c++11 -stdlib=libc++ cpptest.cpp` (or various permutations of that) instead, but that fails horribly, complaining about the linker.

So my question is, how does `clang++` differ from `clang -x c++`? Is it possible to get the above snippet to compile using `clang -x c++` instead of `clang++`?

My machine is a 2012 MacBook Air running Mountain Lion.

### Debugging stuff

Now back at work, I've played a bit more with this, and compared the verbose output of the different versions.

#### Calling `clang -x c++`

When I run `clang -v -x c++ -stdlib=libc++ cpptest.cpp` I get

```
Apple clang version 4.1 (tags/Apple/clang-421.11.66) (based on LLVM 3.1svn)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin12.2.1
Thread model: posix
 "/usr/bin/clang" -cc1 -triple x86_64-apple-macosx10.8.0 -emit-obj -mrelax-all -disable-free -disable-llvm-verifier -main-file-name cpptest.cpp -pic-level 1 -mdisable-fp-elim -relaxed-aliasing -masm-verbose -munwind-tables -target-cpu core2 -target-linker-version 134.9 -v -resource-dir /usr/bin/../lib/clang/4.1 -fmodule-cache-path /var/folders/8m/b4wllzbs67d9zxcj1dd8q6912jclkf/T/clang-module-cache -stdlib=libc++ -fdeprecated-macro -fdebug-compilation-dir /Users/me/Desktop -ferror-limit 19 -fmessage-length 80 -stack-protector 1 -mstackrealign -fblocks -fobjc-runtime-has-arc -fobjc-runtime-has-weak -fobjc-dispatch-method=mixed -fobjc-default-synthesize-properties -fcxx-exceptions -fexceptions -fdiagnostics-show-option -fcolor-diagnostics -o /var/folders/8m/b4wllzbs67d9zxcj1dd8q6912jclkf/T/cpptest-1eOyZn.o -x c++ cpptest.cpp
clang -cc1 version 4.1 based upon LLVM 3.1svn default target x86_64-apple-darwin12.2.1
ignoring nonexistent directory "/usr/include/c++/v1"
#include "..." search starts here:
#include <...> search starts here:
 /usr/bin/../lib/c++/v1
 /usr/local/include
 /usr/bin/../lib/clang/4.1/include
 /usr/include
 /System/Library/Frameworks (framework directory)
 /Library/Frameworks (framework directory)
End of search list.
 "/usr/bin/ld" -demangle -dynamic -arch x86_64 -macosx_version_min 10.8.0 -o a.out /var/folders/8m/b4wllzbs67d9zxcj1dd8q6912jclkf/T/cpptest-1eOyZn.o -lSystem /usr/bin/../lib/clang/4.1/lib/darwin/libclang_rt.osx.a
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
[snip]
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

#### Calling `clang++`

When I call `clang++ -v -stdlib=libc++ cpptest.cpp` I get the following.

```
clang++ -v -stdlib=libc++ cpptest.cpp 
Apple clang version 4.1 (tags/Apple/clang-421.11.66) (based on LLVM 3.1svn)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin12.2.1
Thread model: posix
 "/usr/bin/clang" -cc1 -triple x86_64-apple-macosx10.8.0 -emit-obj -mrelax-all -disable-free -disable-llvm-verifier -main-file-name cpptest.cpp -pic-level 1 -mdisable-fp-elim -relaxed-aliasing -masm-verbose -munwind-tables -target-cpu core2 -target-linker-version 134.9 -v -resource-dir /usr/bin/../lib/clang/4.1 -fmodule-cache-path /var/folders/8m/b4wllzbs67d9zxcj1dd8q6912jclkf/T/clang-module-cache -stdlib=libc++ -fdeprecated-macro -fdebug-compilation-dir /Users/me/Desktop -ferror-limit 19 -fmessage-length 80 -stack-protector 1 -mstackrealign -fblocks -fobjc-runtime-has-arc -fobjc-runtime-has-weak -fobjc-dispatch-method=mixed -fobjc-default-synthesize-properties -fcxx-exceptions -fexceptions -fdiagnostics-show-option -fcolor-diagnostics -o /var/folders/8m/b4wllzbs67d9zxcj1dd8q6912jclkf/T/cpptest-E7FTDV.o -x c++ cpptest.cpp
clang -cc1 version 4.1 based upon LLVM 3.1svn default target x86_64-apple-darwin12.2.1
ignoring nonexistent directory "/usr/include/c++/v1"
#include "..." search starts here:
#include <...> search starts here:
 /usr/bin/../lib/c++/v1
 /usr/local/include
 /usr/bin/../lib/clang/4.1/include
 /usr/include
 /System/Library/Frameworks (framework directory)
 /Library/Frameworks (framework directory)
End of search list.
 "/usr/bin/ld" -demangle -dynamic -arch x86_64 -macosx_version_min 10.8.0 -o a.out /var/folders/8m/b4wllzbs67d9zxcj1dd8q6912jclkf/T/cpptest-E7FTDV.o -lc++ -lSystem /usr/bin/../lib/clang/4.1/lib/darwin/libclang_rt.osx.a
```

#### Differences and solution?

The only major difference I can find is that when I run clang with the `-x c++` flag the `-lc++` flag does not get added at the end of the line that starts with `"/usr/bin/lb"`. When I instead compile with `clang -v -lc++ -x c++ -stdlib=libc++ cpptest.cpp`, everything works. I still don't understand how exactly the `clang++` and `clang -x c++` commands are supposed to differ, but this seems to make my example program compile at least, and seems to indicate that the commands do different things with the linker.

### Solution to my Sublime Text 2 problem

This whole little bug hunt was started with me trying to figure out how to get Sublime Text 2 to stop complaining about code I have that actually works, and now I think I've got it. What was needed was simply to follow the instructions [here](https://github.com/quarnster/SublimeClang/issues/107) and set the includes to be

```
/usr/lib/c++/v1
/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
/usr/include/c++/4.2.1/ext
```

in the `SublimeClang.sublime-settings` file.

Comment: you should add more details about your machine, a considerable amount of features about clang/llvm are only available under Darwin/Mac OS

Answer (score 3):

You're right. There are the difference only for linking stage. You could run clang just for compilation with -c flag and you'll get the same result.

Then you adding the -lc++ flag, boths samples are coming the same.