# Error while trying to create shared library

Tags: c, r, macos, fortran, clang

I am trying to create the shared library (.so) so that I can call it using .External command from R for the lassoshooting package:
https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/lassoshooting/

Basically, I have downloaded the package source from the above website. However, when I go the the correct directory (.../lassoshooting/src) and use the command

```
R CMD SHLIB -o ccd_r.so ccd_r.c
```

I get the following error:

> clang -dynamiclib -Wl,-headerpad_max_install_names -undefined
>   dynamic_lookup -single_module -multiply_defined suppress
>   -L/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/lib -L/usr/local/lib -o ccd_r.so ccd_r.o -L/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/lib
>   -lRblas -L/usr/local/lib/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin13.0.0/4.8.2 -lgfortran -lquadmath -lm -F/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/.. -framework R -Wl,-framework -Wl,CoreFoundation
>
> ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/usr/local/lib/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin13.0.0/4.8.2'
>   ld: library not found for -lgfortran
>   clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation) make: *** [ccd_r.so] Error 1

Why is this happening?

Comment: Maybe `libgfortran` is not installed?

Comment: gfortran is installed. is libgfortran any different? thanks.

Comment: [How to get clang to link against a library without the “lib” prefix?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28219849/how-to-get-clang-to-link-against-a-library-without-the-lib-prefix)

Comment: You need to set `FLIBS` to tell R where to find `libgfortran`. See [my answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29992066/rcpp-warning-directory-not-found-for-option-l-usr-local-cellar-gfortran-4-8) for more details.